# why dropna() is not working as I expect it to?

Tags: python, pandas

I have asked this question already once but deleted it because it did not address the issue in the correct way.

I want to drop all rows that contain `NaN`. I am quite sure I would need to apply

```
df.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)
```

to achieve what I need. But for some unknown reason it simply does not work. I even have the suspicion that it's a software/version related issue. I am working with anaconda and pandas 0.18.0 and conda version  conda version : 4.1.2
  conda-build version : 1.19.0
       python version : 3.5.1.final.0
     requests version : 2.9.1

I create a data frame from csv with following:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('Vols.csv', sep=',', parse_dates=True, 
index_col="Date",usecols=['Date','60DAY_IMPVOL'])
df2 = pd.read_csv('DAX02072016.csv', sep=',', index_col= "Date", parse_dates=True,
usecols=['Date','Close'])
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

What I get is a data frame:

```
         60DAY_IMPVOL        Close
Date
2004-02-03     NaN            4057.510010
2004-02-04     NaN            4028.370117
2004-02-05     NaN            4014.790039
2004-02-06     18.54          4044.989990
2004-02-09     17.76          4098.970215
2004-02-10     NaN            4077.635363
```

and applying dropna() does not make anything, also when I use axis=1 or axis=0. So anyone any suggestion what could be the reason why it's not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`how='all'` doesn't mean "drop *all* rows which contain a NaN", it means "drop rows which are *all* NaN".  You want `how='any'`, which means "drop rows which contain *any* NaN".

```
>>> df.dropna(how='all')
            60DAY_IMPVOL        Close
Date                                 
2004-02-03           NaN  4057.510010
2004-02-04           NaN  4028.370117
2004-02-05           NaN  4014.790039
2004-02-06         18.54  4044.989990
2004-02-09         17.76  4098.970215
2004-02-10           NaN  4077.635363
>>> df.dropna(how='any')
            60DAY_IMPVOL        Close
Date                                 
2004-02-06         18.54  4044.989990
2004-02-09         17.76  4098.970215
```

`how='any'` is actually the default, so to be honest, `df.dropna()` would have worked too.

(Note that `inplace=True` is a little out of favour, and usually we'd just write `df = df.dropna(how='any')` these days.)

Comment: many thanks @DSM, it's just a little embarrassing to have a posted such a question when I look at the answer ;)

Comment: btw, I am facing the same problem. What I want to do is to delete the blank row or NaN, if any, delete the row. And make changes to the file.

Name;Address;Age
;Atlantis;32
Andi;New York;23
John;London;25
;London;32


I want to delete row 1 & 2 (in this example), so I use:
df.dropna(subset=["Name"], inplace = True)

It was working on the screen, but why it did not overwrite the file?